# ExecStopPost is not getting executed if Service is not running in Systemctl

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, systemctl

The issue is that my service is not running and i tried to execute the stop service command. So as the service is not running if i try to stop the service by using systemctl stop $servicename.service the ExecStop command will not get executed and thus my ExecStopPost is also not getting executed.But i want that ExecStopPost command to be executed even though my service is not running and i try to execute the stop service command.

Answer (score 0):

If the service is not running the command given to ExecStopPost will not execute.